# Escape Character for aws CloudWatch Log Query Insights

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I'm working with an api that excecutes an aws Insights query. I check some business layers and then add filters to the query.

Those filters are from a list of errors that I can't change.

The trouble is that I cant make an standard function to add the filters. Now I'm using

```
public CWL_InsightsQuery NotLike(string field, string value, int index = -1) {

        if (index < 0) {
            int Index = QSegments.FindIndex(x => x.StartsWith("filter"));
            QSegments[Index] = QSegments[Index] + " and " + SetInternalField(field) + " not like /"" + value + "/" ";
        } else {
            QSegments[index] = QSegments[index] + " and " + SetInternalField(field) + " not like /"" + value + "/" ";
        }
        return this;
    }
```

QSegments stands for the construction of the query.

In simple terms, I ended up with an string like

```
|filter Data not like "value here lol"
```

this IS working, and its fine. The trouble starts when value has quotation marks, or different special characters.

So, Value can be `this "is a" very 'unique' value /and i hate it/`

so, I cant use '', neither / or " to declare the filter string.

Is there any escape character, as @ in C#?

Would need something in CloudWatch Log insights like

```
@"I love how ""this query"" works 'every' time /i/ need it"
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: I have come here with the same problem.  No pointers to escaping?  I need to escape characters such as `[` and `]`...

Comment: This may be related: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/4577

Comment: @mpettis you can escape them with backward slash e.g. `like /\[ERROR\]/`